# Get Non Indented string from Json Object

Tags: c++, json

I have a json object in c++. I am using json_cpp library.

I want to get the string from the Json::Value object. I am using it like below.

```
Json::Value obj;
....
....
....
string str = obj.toStyledString();
```

This returns the string in the pretty print format. But I want the string without any indentation. How can I do that as there are no other functions provided in the class?

Comment: JSON *is* a character string, normally transmitted without format information.  Any representation as "obj" is not "JSON" but rather a translation of the JSON into the elements of some kit.

Comment: Hint:  What operation created "obj"?  Is there a reverse operation?

Comment: I suppose that toStyledString() is actually a reverse operation :) But it returnes a formatted JSON string while the topic starter wants an unformatted.

Comment: @FreeNickname - I was trying to prompt the OP to actually look at the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Json::FastWriter`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_fast_writer.html) it does not have any indentation and formatting since it outputs everything on a single line. it is normally not suitable for 'human' consumption.

```
std::string toUnStyledString(const Json::Value& value)
{
   Json::FastWriter writer;
   return writer.write( value );
}
```

The function `toStyledString` also simply uses a [`Json::StyledWriter`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_styled_writer.html) if you look into the definition of `Json::Value::toStyledString`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this library doesn't provide appropriate methods then you could write them yourself. The JSON format is rather simple, so I don't think that it will take a lot of work.
Here you can find a good graphical representation of JSON format:

http://json.org

P.S. I've never worked with this particular library, so I propose sort of a general solution.

**UPDATE:** another option is to get a string returned by toStyledString() and remove indentation. But it requires string processing and will probably be resource consuming. Note that you can't just remove tabs/spaces/new line symbols, because they can be a part of JSON object.
Why do you want unindented string again?